# C#, winforms, devexpress gridview . Edit the active cell without blinking cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Edit the active cell without blinking cursor. ( I have set to grid cell repository text edit which I try to use as an empty placeholder.
When an user select a cell then nothing should happen. However I cannot achevie this task. Whenever cell become focused there is a cursor blinking. Blinking cursor may suggest that user can input there something while I do not want this.
When text edit is read only it should not blink. )

Comment: This sounds like homework, is it? SO is a community where we help eachother debug code and find solutions to code problems but we are not here to do homework for people. If your running into a specific problem please post your code where the problem is at, a description of the problem, and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in FormLoad:

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```